# Internal Server Error with web.config ipSecurity

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

This is my web.config which has some tags for blocking Ipaddress

```
<configuration>
 <connectionStrings>
    ...
 </connectionStrings>
 <appSettings>
  ....
 </appSettings> 
 <runtime>
   ....
 </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <security> 
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false"> 
            <clear/> 
             <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true"/>
             <add ipAddress="83.116.19.53" allowed="true"/> 
        </ipSecurity>  
    </security>
</system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

My intention is to block any other IP except the above. The above is the only Ip address I want the website to be accessible from . But with "ipSecurity" tag I am always getting
500 - Internal server error and the site runs fine without it.

I have made sure that "IP and Domains Restrictions" are installed on the server.
Please let me know if I am missing anything.
Thank you.

Comment: Also add `::1` for IPv6 localhost, check your access logs for the site to see what IP address is being blocked if it is still not working after that. If you're on a remote location verify your public ip via something like ipchicken.com

Comment: Thanks I tried IPv6 localhost but it did not help. From the IIS when I try to click the "IP & Domain Restrictions" it throughs me an error "locking is either by default (overridemodedefault= deny )".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you editing the config by hand or through IIS manager?

See this post about that error message as you may not have that **feature delegation** enabled

http://forums.asp.net/t/1220987.aspx

Comment: The link is down ... :( "The site you're trying to reach is down for maintenance..."

Answer (score 43):

For others that run into this issue.  The cause of the issue is that Feature Delegation doesn't allow the feature to be managed by web.config.

To Fix:

Verify that the Feature is enabled for web.config management

- In IIS 7, click on the root server
- Double click Feature Delegation (under management)
- Scroll down to IPv4 Address and Domain Restrictions

  - Change the delegation to Read/Write (in my case it was Read Only, which was the issue)

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: This solved my issue but couldn't see "IPv4 Address and Domain Restrictions" until installed Win7 -> Programs and Features -> World Wide Web Services -> Application Development Features -> ASP and also in World Wide Web Services -> Application Development Features -> Security -> IP Security.

Comment: Thanks! This exactly solve my issue after I have fix the issues in the applicationHost.config

Comment: Absolute legend. I'm sure Brock's answer is also correct, but this is much more succinct.

Comment: This answer helped me in 2014, and again in 2020.

Answer (score 22):

For Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 note that the ApplicationHost.config file has been relocated to the .vs\config folder in your project's folder hierarchy.  You will need to **edit the project specific version of the ApplicationHost.config** file found there with...

```
<section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

If you only edit the ApplicationHost.config located in your Documents\IISExpress folder this will not affect your existing application (MVC5 appl in my case).

Comment: In my case there was no ApplicationHost.config file in the .vs\config folder. In fact there was no config folder under .vs. I had to edit the one on Documents\IISExpress to solve the problem. This is on Win 10 using VS 2019.

Comment: To clarify: "Project-specific" means there is a directory set up specifically for that project. Once I identified the right `applicationhost.config` file, then it worked: `.vs\{project_folder}\config\applicationhost.config`. There may also be one in the main `.vs/config` folder AND in the user `Documents\IISExpress\config` folder. The most specific designation will be used.

Answer (score 11):

Open the *applicationHost.config* file (located at *%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config*) and edit the **ipSecurity** section.

Change this line:

```
<section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

To:

```
<section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Comment: If you are working on a 64bit system. Make sure to edit and save it with a program that is 64bit! (like notepad)

Answer (score 6):

Try this outside System.Webserver tag

```
<location path="Default WebSite">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
                <clear/>                 
               <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true"/>
             <add ipAddress="83.116.19.53" allowed="true"/> 
            </ipSecurity>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Comment: Isn't this setting allowing connection from all sources, because allowUnlisted is set to true?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/

Comment: @Mino Good Catch! Updated my answer.

Comment: This is a better solution because affect only 1 website, all other proposed solutions affects all websites in server, and maybe you can not use in hosting environments.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this will help someone...

I am running IIS express on Windows 7 locally and did the following - **Control panel > Programs > Programs and features > Turn Windows features on or off**

In the **Windows Features** dialog ensure the **IP Security** option is checked:

[image]

I also had to open up my applicationhost.config (under **%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config**) file and change the following:

```
<section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

To

```
<section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget custom site delegation.  This allows you to only allow delegation to sites you intend.