# Allow "localhost" to run in iisexpress when web.config contains ipSecurity permissions

Tags: web-config, localhost, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I just added this to my web.config:

```
<security>
  <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
    <!-- The following IP addresses are granted access, all else denied -->
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="123.123.105.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0" />
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="123.123.100.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0" />
  </ipSecurity>
</security>
```

Works exactly as intended, only over that certain IP range.  BUT, now when I go to test this in Visual Studio via iisExpress over localhost it of course gives me issues. Here is the 500.19 error I receive:

```
This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
```

I have setup IPSecurity on my localmachine in the services panel, so that is enabled, and I have monkeyed around with options in the ipSecurity block such as adding 'localhost' as a domainName value - but alas no luck. .... help me StackOverflow, you're my only hope! ;)

Comment: I'm also having this problem and can't seem to find a solution either

Answer (score 17):

I just ran into the same situation. I googled around and found that all you have to do is edit the **applicationhost.config** file for IIS Express found here:

*%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config*

Open it up and look for the **ipSecurity** section that is inside the **system.webServer** section and change **overrideModeDefault** from "Deny" to "Allow". You do not need to add the IIS **IP Security** from Windows Features.

```
<sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
  <sectionGroup name="security">
    ...
    <section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    ...
  </sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
```

Hope this helps!

NOTE: For **Windows 10** and **Visual Studio 2015 (or later version)** please note that the ApplicationHost.config file **has been relocated to the .vs\config folder in your project's folder hierarchy**.

Comment: Did that, and it seems to have gotten me a bit closer - now I receive the following error: HTTP Error 403.503 - Forbidden
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Comment: The 403.502 and 503 codes are related to the IP restriction module in IIS. I believe you may be blocking yourself out. (http://forums.iis.net/p/1210696/2075884.aspx?Re+IIS+8+IP+Restrictions+HTTP+403+503+Code)
EDIT: Oh wait! You have to add localhost to your allow list.
<add allowed="true" ipAddress="127.0.0.1" subnetMask="255.255.255.255" />

Comment: There must be something more to it. I've already tried this on two different PCs - and it doesn't work. I'm still getting the same error message "This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when..." on both.

Comment: See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33710459/261690 - under VS2015 the applicationhost.config is now in a project-specific location.

Comment: look for this section in the file: sectionGroup name="system.webServer"

Answer (score 2):

Add 127.0.0.1 to your allowed ips like so:

```
<add allowed="true" ipAddress="127.0.0.1" />
```

Thanks to @AbeyMarquez, I thought your comment warranted more attention as it solved my problem.  Thanks!