# Can't add localhost IP Address to ipsecurity section of web.config file ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, http-error

I want to add the local host ip address to the list of allowed ip addresses for my site in web.config, so that when I start up the local debugger in IIS Express I'm not blocked. I'm following these two pages with no luck. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508700/allow-localhost-to-run-in-iisexpress-when-web-config-contains-ipsecurity-permi) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220819/internal-server-error-with-web-config-ipsecurity/33710459#33710459)

So I added it like this, but it still blocks me.

```html
<security>
  <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound">
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="127.0.0.1" subnetMask="255.255.255.255" /> 
    // my true ip address
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="24.130.112.30" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" />


  </ipSecurity>
</security>
```

I also tried adding

```
<section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

in the applicationhost.config file in wondows.

But I'm still getting this error message in the browser

[image]

Comment: please refer to my two links, that include the one you used. I've already tried it

Comment: If you have followed all suggestions in the link, have you considered employing web.config transformation.  Essentially putting the section in only in production? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue as you. I read somewhere that there can also be an applicationhost.config file stored in your projects .vs\config\ folder. I changed the overrideModeDefault value in this file and everything started working.