# ASP.Net How to limit access to a particular IP address to a particular page through web.config file (.htaccess similar)?

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, web-config

The project I'm working on contains three folder under "Views" folder: Home, Shared, and Data folders.

What can I add to my `web.config` file to deny everyone access except people with IP address xxx.x.xx.xx?

Essentially, what would be the equivalent of placing a `.htaccess` file inside the "Data" folder under views with the code:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xxx.x.xx.xx
```

Is there a way to do this without active directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On IIS7 use IPSecurity to restrict by IP address:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">          
       <clear/>
       <add ipAddress="xxx.x.xx.xx" allowed="true"/>  
    </ipSecurity>
  </security>
```

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity

Similar topics: [Best way to restrict access by IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431013/best-way-to-restrict-access-by-ip-address), [Internal Server Error with web.config ipSecurity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220819/internal-server-error-with-web-config-ipsecurity), http://www.victor-ratajczyk.com/post/2011/12/21/Webconfig-ipSecurity-Allow-specific-IP-addresses-Deny-all-others.aspx

Comment: What if I want to allow specific range of IP address only

Comment: @Prakash You can provide a subnetMask.

<add ipAddress="169.254.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" />